# How to persist messages in Postgresql's LISTEN/NOTIFY?

Tags: postgresql, event-notification, queue

If I send notifications before starting to listen i.e.

```
notify test, 'test message';
listen test;
```

I loose that notifications. How can I persist them for later fetching?
Actually, I need this notifications for tables updates, so it is preferably not to start spezialized messaging system like RMQ etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because nothing more about it can be said then what I said. It doesn't do that. None of the docs would lead you to believe it does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't replay them. If no one is listening, they're gone. Start up your own communication daemon to catch them. Then you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, I will start my own daemon, but I can't guarantee it will work without interruptions. I want secure myself from losing messages.

Comment: Then don't use listen/notify. Insert into a table called messages and have something read them and reap them.

Comment: Hope, this is not the only solution

Comment: Ever try to open a bottle with a can opener? I hope that's also not the only solution.

Comment: Please, don't kill my hope :)

Comment: There is no hope. It's the wrong tool for the job. It's just not what NOTIFY/LISTEN does. If you need the message stored in another table (queue), you need to create another table and write to it. Or, use an audit table. There are lots of methods that probably do what you want, but LISTEN/NOTIFY has nothing to do with it.

Comment: As I see, no one can suggest a solution and the only thing we can do in this situation (like @EvanCarroll said) is to create the support table and use trigger `CREATE TRIGGER notes_trigger AFTER INSERT or UPDATE
   ON journals
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE alert_update_notes();` with a function, that inserts data to it `INSERT INTO ...` **and** _notify_ daemon `PERFORM pg_notify ...` The daemon will process the notification with _listen_ and delete data from the support table. I'd like to create answer with detailed description, if the ticket will be unlocked.

Comment: @AstraSerg Why are you using the PostgreSQL `NOTIFY` infrastructure at all? That's what I'm confused about. That plan is also a bad idea. What happens if "notify daemon" recasts the event and the receiving daemon crashes, or the connection is lost in transit? It's not made for fault tolerance. Your task requires that, so factor out `NOTIFY/LISTEN`. Just write to a table and read from it. If you need transaction safety, use the built in transactions not `NOTIFY/LISTEN`.

Comment: I need to use `NOTIFY/LISTEN` becouse it is the only way to get info about table changes with **push** scheme, not **pull**. I described this in my question: `I need this notifications for tables updates`

Comment: @AstraSerg there is no push scheme that has `retry` that makes it a fundamentally *unsafe* operation. You're only option is to pull. So simply `SELECT` from the table every 50 ms. It'll be just as fast because you don't have to listen for events and then `SELECT`.

Comment: Are you really suggesting me to create 72000 request per hour per table when only 5-10 of them will be productive? Even if do not take into account the size of transferred data (which may be huge) it is ridiculous. Hope I understood you wrong :)

Comment: Yes. I am, because they'll read from the buffer anyway. While 50ms isn't a problem, I would probably be a bit more reasonable. Unless you need that resolution.